# How to compare two datatables and only check for the rows found

Tags: c#, linq

```
var qry = from r1 in dtCMS.AsEnumerable() //row count - 416
          from r2 in dtEcho.AsEnumerable() //row count - 175
          where
              r1.Field<string>("Name") == r2.Field<string>("Name")
          select r2;

DataTable dt1 = dtEcho.AsEnumerable().Except(qry).CopyToDataTable();
```

Error:

> The source contains no DataRows.

How can I modify the code above so that the comparison will only happen for the rows in `r2`?

I would like two functions:

- One, that compare `dtEcho` to `dtCMS`, and return anything that is in
  `dtEcho` but not in `dtCMS`.
- Two, that compare `dtEcho` to `dtCMS`, and return anything that is in
  `dtCMS` but not in `dtEcho`.

The code fails if the DataTable I am comparing against has more rows and hence it can't compare.

Comment: have you tried dtEcho.Tables["tableName"].Rows ?

Comment: I guess you are tryingto compare two DataTables to determine rows in one but not the other

Comment: @DeJaVo You got what I am trying to do... I would like two functions. One, that compare `dtEcho` to `dtCMS`, and return anything that is in `dtEcho` but not in `dtCMS. Two, that compare `dtEcho` to `dtCMS`, and return anything that is in `dtCMS` but not in `dtEcho`.

Comment: Your code is correct and the only thing that you should change is the way that you create the result. Instead of `CopyToDataTable` put results in the result table using a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

[`CopyToDataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx) will throw an `InvalidOperationException` if the source sequence does not contain any `DataRow` objects:

> The source contains no DataRows.

Your code is OK in general and to solve the problem with minimum changes, the only thing that you should change is the way that you create the result.

Instead of using `CopyToDataTable` put results in the result table using a for loop. To do so, first you should create a clone of your second table.

```
var qry = from r1 in table1.AsEnumerable() //row count - 416
          from r2 in table2.AsEnumerable() //row count - 175
          where
              r1.Field<string>("Name") == r2.Field<string>("Name")
          select r2;


var dt = table2.Clone();
table2.AsEnumerable().Except(qry).ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    dt.Rows.Add(x);
});
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got right what you want, the code should look like this:

```
// setup
var dtCMS = new DataTable();
dtCMS.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dtCMS.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));

for (int i = 0; i < 416; i++)
    dtCMS.Rows.Add(i, "Name " + i);

var dtEcho = new DataTable();
dtEcho.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dtEcho.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));

for (int i = 400; i < 575; i++)
    dtEcho.Rows.Add(i, "Name " + i);

// convert to enumerables
var cmsEnum = dtCMS.AsEnumerable();
var echoEnum = dtEcho.AsEnumerable();

var CmsMinusEcho = cmsEnum.Where(cms => !echoEnum.Any(echo => echo.Field<String>("Name").Equals(cms.Field<String>("Name"))));
var EchoMinusCms = echoEnum.Where(echo => !cmsEnum.Any(cms => cms.Field<String>("Name").Equals(echo.Field<String>("Name"))));

// get DataTable with check
var CmsMinusEchoDt = CmsMinusEcho.Count() > 0 ? CmsMinusEcho.CopyToDataTable() : null;
var EchoMinusCmsDt = EchoMinusCms.Count() > 0 ? EchoMinusCms.CopyToDataTable() : null;
```

Comment: Thanks but the row count is dynamic

Comment: dtCMS and dtEcho initialization is done only to provide a fully working example. You have to use only what is after that: // convert to enumerables ...

Comment: now I see what you are doing. +1, will accept after testing. Thanks.